# Auto suggestion in Jupyter while tying

Tags: jupyter

When you are coding in jupyter it almost feels like a text editor where no suggesting are made inline while typing such as most full compilers make. Is there a way where Jyputer will also auto suggest definitions from class while coding so it gives a compiler like such as of pycharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press tab, then you will see suggestions. 
Jupyter can not generate suggestions for it's own.